# What's wrong with 4...e5 in the Open Sicilian?

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense, 1.e4

I like to play 4...e5 in the Open Sicilian in my games, usually facing something like this:

```
[StartPly "8"]

[fen ""]
1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 e5 5. Nb3 Nc6
```

I do this to:

1. Chase the knight so that it doesn't block advancing my pieces.
2. Regain control of the center after 3...cxd4.
3. Gain a tempo.

Is there any disadvantage in doing this ?

Comment: To me it seems it wouldn't be long until that d pawn became weak. It is going to be a while until it reaches d4 and is defended by the e pawn and since there is no black c pawn, it can't be defended by a pawn chain in the near future. It can also turn into an isolated pawn after f4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 e5 5.Nb3 Nc6, the position is probably fine for black.

However, after 4....e5, white seems to have a stronger reply: 5.Bb5+. According to the [Game Database of ChessTempo](http://chesstempo.com/game-database.html), this is also the most popular move. Now, black has two options: 4....Bd7 or 4....Nd7. After both moves, white can put his knight on f5 and obtain a slightly better position.

Therefore, I would say that 4....e5 is a small inaccuracy. However, the *ideas* behind the move (occupying the center, gaining a tempo) are perfectly fine.

Maybe it is interesting to take a look at:

- the Sveshnikov variation: 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 e5
- the Kalashnikov variation: 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 e5
- the Classical variation: 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 Nc6, and after 6.Be2, 6....e5
- the Najdorf variation: 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 a6, and after 6.Be2, 6....e5

```
      [FEN ""]
      [StartPly "3"]

      1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 (2...Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 (4...e5) 5.Nc3 e5) 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 e5 (4...Nf6 5.Nc3 a6 (5...Nc6 6.Be2 e5) 6.Be2 e5) 5.Bb5+ (5.Nb3 Nc6) 5...Nd7 (5...Bd7 6.Bxd7+ Qxd7 7.Nf5) 6.Nf5
```

Comment: These variations seem very interesting. I particularly like the Najdorf variation of the idea.

Comment: The Najdorf is a good opening and probably the most popular Sicilian. The e5-idea is not always good in this variation however. For instance, after 6.Bc4 or 6.Bg5, you should not play 6....e5, as it weakens the d5-square too much. Good luck!

Comment: I think the obvious reason not to play e5 here is that the d pawn is backwards and for White to attack the d pawn is a theme in the Sicilian.